# Use specifc HashMap value to setText() of a specific TextView

Tags: android, hashmap, textview

In an Android app I have various `TextView` instances whose IDs are something like: `android:id="@+id/a_key` where `a_key` is a word with no numerical values.

A Java class (not activity) parses an external XML file and populates a Map like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>;
map.put(a_key, a_value);
```

where the String `a_key` contains the exact same word of `android:id="@id/a_key"`.

How would I go on about assigning `a_value` to the `android:text` resource whose ID is represented by the String `a_key`?

I apologize if this is confusing. I can post the code if it helps, but I tried to keep it as generic as possible.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this would be with the way codeMagic suggested.

Using

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("a_key", "id", "com.example.app");
```

Then of course using

```
Textview a_textView = findViewById(id);
```

You will need to iterate through the entry set of the map to do it this way so use

```
 map.entrySet()
```

ex:

```
for(Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(entry.getKey(), "id", "com.example.app");
    TextView textView = findViewById(id);
    textView.setText(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Turns out this was the ideal option, at least on paper. Unfortuantely `getResources().getIdentifier(entry.getKey(), "id", "com.example.app");` returns `null`, even though I know for a fact that the map is passed (`Log.d("TAG", entry.getKey().toString())` returns the relevant key). And I can't understand why.

Comment: Make sure you are using your package, not com.example.app

Comment: I hardcoded all 13 instances to keep going with the rest of the app, I'll review it down the road. I use `getResources().getIdentifier();` successfully elsewhere, using `getPackageName()` instead of `"com.example.myapp"`, so when I must have put the wrong argument when I tried it initially. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `id` is converted to an `integer` and lost to the system at compile time. So that isn't the way to do it. The best idea is to use the tag on each `text view`: `android:tag="a_key"`.  Then when you want to set the text of the view, use `getTag` to get the tag, and pass it into the hash map to get the associated string.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll try it out. Thank you!

Comment: "the id is converted to an integer and lost to the system at compile time" *scratches head* http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: And utterly useless here-  if you already knew the name (the first parameter of that call), there'd be no need for this question.  The thing to point out to me should have been getResourceEntryName, which may actually be a good replacement for the tags here to avoid double entry bugs, but which I haven't used so I'm not entirely sure works the way I'd hope.

Comment: The question is asking exactly this. He said he knows the id name but needs to find the int id...

Also if you are already setting the tag to the id name, you can just use findViewWithTag("a_key") instead and save yourself trouble

Answer (score 0):

You say your HashMap is not in an Activity, but you won't be able to set the text for a TextView unless you are in an Activity. So let's assume that your HashMap is available from that class. The following should work in your Activity:

```
TextView testTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
HashMap<String, String> map = otherClassInstance.getMap();
testTextView.setText(map.get("testTextView"));
```

The fragility here is that if you refactor the ID, you'll also need to remember to change the hard-coded text in your call to `setText()`. For that reason Gabe's solution is probably better for your case.